# Listing prime numbers using Sieve's method using bitmask

Tags: c, arrays, primes, bitmask, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I wrote the following code to list all the prime numbers upto 2 billion using Sieve's method. I used bitmasking for flagging purpose. While I am able to get the prime numbers correctly, a few primes in the beginning are missing every time. Please help me find the bug in the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 2000000000

char* listPrimes(){
int block = sqrt(MAX);
char* mark = calloc((MAX/8),sizeof(char));
int i = 2;
int j;
char mask[8];
for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    mask[j] = 0;
mask[7] = 1;
mask[6] |= mask[7] << 1;
mask[5] |= mask[7] << 2;
mask[4] |= mask[7] << 3;
mask[3] |= mask[7] << 4;
mask[2] |= mask[7] << 5;
mask[1] |= mask[7] << 6;
mask[0] |= mask[7] << 7;

for(j=0;j<8;j++)
    printf("%d ",mask[j]);
mark[0] |= mask[0];
mark[0] |= mask[1];

while (i < block){

        for (j = 2; i*j <= block; j++)
                mark[(i*j) / 8] |= mask[((i*j) % 8 )];
        i++;
    }
printf("\n");
printf("The block size is\t:\t%d\n",block);


j = 2;
while(j<=block){
    if((mark[j / 8] & mask[j]) == 0 ){
        for(i = 2;i <= MAX; i++){
            if((i%j) == 0){
                mark[i / 8] |= mask[(i % 8)];
            }
        }
    }
while((mark[++j / 8] & mask[j % 8]) != 0);
}


for(j=0;j<=MAX;j++)
        if((mark[j / 8] & mask[(j % 8)]) == 0)
            printf("%d\n", ((8*(j / 8)) + (j % 8)));

return mark;
}   

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

listPrimes();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ArunMK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1952500/arunmk) said, in the second `while` loop you mark the prime `j` itself as a multiple of `j`. And as [Lee Meador](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932588/lee-meador) said, you need to take the modulus of `j` modulo 8 for the `mask` index, otherwise you access out of bounds and invoke undefined behaviour.

A further point where you invoke undefined behaviour is

```
while((mark[++j / 8] & mask[j % 8]) != 0);
```

where you use and modify `j` without intervening sequence point. You can avoid that by writing

```
do {
    ++j;
}while((mark[j/8] & mask[j%8]) != 0);
```

or, if you insist on a `while` loop with empty body

```
while(++j, (mark[j/8] & mask[j%8]) != 0);
```

you can use the comma operator.

More undefined behaviour by accessing `mark[MAX/8]` which is not allocated in

```
for(i = 2;i <= MAX; i++){
```

and

```
for(j=0;j<=MAX;j++)
```

Also, if `char` is signed and eight bits wide,

```
mask[0] |= mask[7] << 7;
```

is implementation-defined (and may raise an implementation-defined signal) since the result of

```
mask[0] | (mask[7] << 7)
```

(the `int` 128) is not representable as a `char`.

But why are you dividing each number by all primes not exceeding the square root of the bound in the second `while` loop?

```
    for(i = 2;i <= MAX; i++){
        if((i%j) == 0){
```

That makes your algorithm not a Sieve of Eratosthenes, but a trial division.

Why don't you use the technique from the first `while` loop there too? (And then, why two loops at all?)

```
while (i <= block){
    if ((mark[i/8] & mask[i%8]) == 0) {
        for (j = 2; i*j < MAX; j++) {
            mark[(i*j) / 8] |= mask[((i*j) % 8 )];
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

would not overflow (for the given value of `MAX`, if that is representable as an `int`), and produce the correct output orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: The ++j is defined to happen before the value of j is used either place since evaluation is guaranteed to be left to right. There is no need to change the 'while'. However, your suggested code is easier to read and understand particularly in 2012 where using the ++ operator this way is frowned upon and newer developers may find it unfamiliar.

Comment: "since evaluation is guaranteed to be left to right." No, it isn't. The order of evaluation of the operands of `&` is unspecified, and the storing of the incremented value is not guaranteed to have happened before the next sequence point. So even if `mark[++j/8]` is evaluated first, the `mask[j%8]` might still read the unincremented value of `j`. Compile with `-Wsequence-point` (and optimisations) and your gcc will warn you about it.

Comment: You are right. I am wrong. Only && and || guarantee left to right and they don't guarantee the expression to the right is even evaluated at all. There are some other obvious ones like , and ?: that have an ordering. 'comma' is there specifically to do things in order and ?: has to evaluate the condition to tell which of the other two expressions to evaluate.

Comment: What is that 2nd loop supposed to accomplish? All the multiples of the primes should already be marked in the 1st loop. Even your suggestion to check for the current i already being marked as a multiple of something smaller doesn't make it work it just makes it more efficient by skipping when we know all the multiples are already set.

Comment: In the original, the first loop only marks to the square root of the limit, so the second is necessary to mark the composites `> block = sqrt(MAX)`. My suggestion is to use only the one loop, and only mark multiples of primes. It works. I have omitted the obvious improvements (start at `i*i`, don't compute `i*j` but increment `j` by `i` [`2*i` for odd `i`], ...) to stay close to the OP's code.

Comment: I missed your change to the end of the inner loop from 'block' to 'MAX'. You could also halfen the size of the array or reduce the time (by pre-OR-ing with 0xCC) by noting that bits 0, 2, 4 and 6 are set in all bytes but the 1st one but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: Yes, removing the even numbers from the sieve is one of the "obvious improvements" I didn't mention. For the given `MAX`, that should be done, probably also multiples of 3 should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Change the middle loop to add the modulo:

```
j = 2;
while(j<=block){
    if((mark[j / 8] & mask[j % 8]) == 0 ){
        for(i = 2;i <= MAX; i++){
            if((i%j) == 0){
                mark[i / 8] |= mask[(i % 8)];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second while loop you are looping through i from 2 onwards and you do an `if (i%j == 0)`. This will be true for i when it is a prime as well. You need to check for (i != j). Also the modulo as reported above. Hence it becomes:
`if ((i%j == 0) {
        if (i!=j)
                mark[i/j] |= mask[i%j];
}`

Comment: Or change this loop `for(i = 2;i <= MAX; i++)` to start at `2*j`